# wget in cron: write to system only if no error encountered/file not empty

Tags: cron, wget

I have the following crontab to pull an online resource at 9am every day and write it to a file locally:

```
0 9 * * * /usr/bin/wget --http-user=username --http-password=password https://remote_file_to_pull.json -O /local_output_file.json >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The problem is that sometimes when retrieving the remote file, the server throws a Error 500. What `wget` does is write over an empty file.

Is there a way to change the `cron` to only write the file if `wget` does not encounter an error and/or the file to write is not empty?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that wget can do what you ask, but if you were to use a temp file and replace the real file on success you wouldn't need wget to do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your crontab entry with a reference to this script, which updates the output only on success from `wget` *and* where it returns a file with non-zero length

```
#!/bin/bash
#
url='https://remote_file_to_pull.json'
user='username'
pass='password'

target='/local_output_file.json'

if wget --quiet --http-user="$user"--http-password="$pass" -O "$target.tmp" "$url" && [[ -s "$target.tmp" ]]
then
    # Success
    mv -f "$target.tmp" "$target"
else
    # Failure of some sort; you might want to report this
    :
fi
rm -f "$target.tmp"
```

By the way. I'm hoping your code was illustrative, but it's generally not good practice to write files directly to the root of the filesystem.